# android: custom view layout wrapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-custom-view

I want to have two custom views like this:

```
class LoadingView extends RelativeLayout{
    //this view has a progressBar and can show and hide it.

    void setIsLoading(){
        // shows/hides progress bar
    }


    // some code ...
}

class OtherView extends LoadingView{
    //some code ...
}
```

LoadingView has a layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        id="@+id/content">
        <!--this is where content goes-->
    </FrameLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        id="@+id/pb"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

so that any custom view that inherits from it will be injected into `FrameLayout`

so if `OtherView` has it's own layout , it will be nested inside `FrameLayout` automatically and you will be able to call `myOtherView.setIsLoading(true/false)`

How would you suggest doing this ?

Comment: You could add a method `public View onCreateContentView()` inside `LoadingView` - default: return null . Have subclasses override this method and return something meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the content `FrameLayout` when inflating the first view.

```
public class LoadingView extends RelativeLayout {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private FrameLayout contentFrame;

    public LoadingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public LoadingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public LoadingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        View root = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.loading_view, this);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        contentFrame = (FrameLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    }

    public void setLoading(boolean loading) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(loading ? VISIBLE : GONE);
    }

    protected FrameLayout getContentFrame() {
        return contentFrame;
    }

}
```

Then use `getContentFrame` as the parent view when inflating the child view.

```
public class OtherView extends LoadingView {

    public OtherView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public OtherView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public OtherView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        View root = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.other_view, getContentFrame());
    }

}
```

`loading_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`other_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="Subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And use it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.example.client.ui.OtherView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```